# Continuous line numbering when mixing single and double columns in reledpar

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

I have a text consisting of some single column and some double column passages. I want to have continuous line numbering throughout the page. Left and right column line numbers should always be synchronized. At each page break the line counter should be reset to 1.

In the following example everything works fine on page 1. But on page two, note how the right column starts with line number 1, where it should be line number 19.

Where is my mistake? Note: I cannot easily reproduce this behavior in all circumstances. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It seems to be connected with where page breaks occur, but I am not sure, what triggers the problem.

I am using reledmac 2021/03/08 v2.37.1 and reledpar 2021/03/08 v2.25.1a.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[widthliketwocolumns,continuousnumberingwithcolumns]{reledpar}

\listfiles

\lineation*{page}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
\pend

\pausenumbering
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\resumenumbering
\pstart
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
This is the left column.
\pend
\pausenumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
This is the right column.
\pend
\pausenumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\resumenumbering

\pstart
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
\pend

\pstart
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
Normal paragraph. Quite ordinary.
\pend



\pstart
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
Now we have a normal paragraph which is long enough to
create a page break.
\pend

\pausenumbering

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\resumenumbering
\pstart
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
On the left column, numbering is OK.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\resumenumbering
\pstart
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
On the right column, however, numbering is out of synch.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

[image: out of synch line numbers on page 2, right column]

Comment: Well, that is because `continuousnumberingwithcolumns` does not work well with lineation by page. So it is a bug.

Comment: So a good news : I found how to solve the bug. But please, open a github issue (the methodes is explained in the handbook).

Comment: This is great, @Maïeul! Thank you very much! The issue is opened here: [https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/928](https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/928)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of reledpar has fixed the bug, so this problem is solved and the fixed version will find its way into one of the next releases, I believe.